# Benefit of not overloading `AbstractCollection.add()` and having `AbstractCollection.addAll()`?

Tags: java, methods

example:

```
public class Something {
    private Set<String> names = new HashSet();

    public void add(String n) { names.add(n); }
    public void add(Set<String> set) { names.addAll(set); }
}
```

But, I am curious why `AbstractCollection.add(E e)` is not overloaded in the same way I overload my `Something.add(String n)`. Why is there the distinct `AbstractCollection.addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)`?

I can't imagine it makes any practical difference.
So, my conclusion is to only overload when there is strong, logical, reason to do so. Overloading just because I can is discouraged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @MetaFight points out, `add` and `addAll` have different semantics.  But there is also a historical perspective to the `Collection` API design.

The Collections framework was added to Java before it supported generic types.  In those days, the API for Collection defined the methods as follows:

```
   boolean add(Object e)          // adds a single element

   boolean addAll(Collection c)   // adds all elements in the collection
```

Now imagine they had instead designed the API like this:

```
   boolean add(Object e)          // adds a single element

   boolean add(Collection c)      // adds all elements in the collection
```

and someone wrote this:

```
   List list = new ArrayList();
   Object list2 = new ArrayList();
   List list3 = new ArrayList();
   list3.add(list);
   list3.add(list2);
```

Question: What would list3 now contain?  Answer: one empty list.

Confusing ... isn't it!  But this neatly illustrates the danger of having overloads do substantially different things.

Now from Java 5, you would (should) declare the lists with parameterized types (not raw types) and the above (hypothetical) example would most likely give you compilation errors.  But, remember, Collections were introduced a few years before generic types.  Even if they had wanted to rename `addAll` as an overload of `add`, they couldn't have done this without breaking binary compatibility.

---

> I can't imagine it makes any practical difference.

It does.  See example above ... for an illustration of the general principle.

> So, my conclusion is to only overload when there is strong, logical, reason to do so. Overloading just because I can is discouraged?

Yes, and Yes.  But also, you should only overload when the methods do *essentially the same thing*.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `add` and `addlAll` have different **meanings**.

`add` is for adding a **single item** to the collection.

`addAll` is for adding **multiple items** to the collection.

Since both methods means something different it makes sense to give them distinct names.